# EWS attachments can't be updated error

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to iterate through attachments in an `EmailMessage` object.

I'm getting error "attachemnts can't be updated" in this line:

```
fa.ContentId = fa.Id;
```

my code is:

```
EmailMessage emailMsg = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(emailId), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments,ItemSchema.Body,ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,EmailMessageSchema.DisplayCc,EmailMessageSchema.DisplayTo,EmailMessageSchema.Subject,EmailMessageSchema.From));
            this.Email = msgItem;
            this.Email.Load();
            // make sure email has id or contentid
            foreach (Attachment attachment in this.Email.Attachments)
            {
                FileAttachment fa = attachment as FileAttachment;
                if (fa.ContentId == null && fa.Id != null)
                {
                    fa.Load();
                    fa.ContentId = fa.Id; // error attachments can't be updated
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't update an Attachment on an existing Exchange Item eg the only valid Attachment operations are Get, Create, Delete there is no Update. The only valid context where you could set the ContentId is when your creating the Message where this property would be set in the CreateAttachment operation. To update an existing attachment you would have to remove it and then re add it as a new attachment. What you actually trying to achieve with your code ?

Cheers
Glen

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to show the users their emails with their attachments. The user can download the attachment by clicking on a link that consist a unique url made of the attachment's contentid field of the file. this method works fine but the problem is that sometimes the contentid is null so I wanted to make sure it has a value.

Comment: Why are you using the ContentId then why don't you just use the AttachmentId that EWS returns it make no sense to do what your trying if your using EWS ? If your working with a POP or IMAP client then just grab the whole message via MIME and parse the attachment back out of that. Unless you have control over the creation of the Messages you won't be able to set the contentId after the Item has been committed to the store without deleting and recreating the attachment which is an ugly solution.

Comment: The reason that I'm using contentid is because I want that the user will be able to download the attachment on the email composing form (I'm using MVC 4). While creating an attachment the only solution is to assign a contentid as a unique identifier and by doing that the user can download his attachment before sending the email. I'm looking for a global solution for both cases: download attachment before sending it and downloading an attachment form a received email.

Comment: Okay but the code you have posted shows you binding to an existing Item and trying to update the ContentId of an Attachment this won't work because there is no underlying EWS method to update an Attachment once it has been created. (you can do it MAPI but not EWS). So in the case where you don't have ContentId on a message like this your only option would be delete and re-Add the Attachment. (Another option maybe to download the MimeCotent of the whole message update the MimeContent and then post that back in an update).